# Extending PrimeFaces's dataTable handling of columns

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, custom-component

I'm trying to extend PrimeFaces's column component within a dataTable - primarily to create headers and to auto-insert the object's field based on a key value without having to manually insert column tags with their associated facets.

I have the following in my my custom component overridng DataTableRenderer:

```
@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
        throws java.io.IOException {
    Object columnOrder = component.getAttributes().get("columnOrder");
    if (columnOrder != null) {

        component.getChildren().clear();

        Application application = context.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();

        Column column = new Column();

        Object var = component.getAttributes().get("var");
        String varKey = columnOrder.toString();

        UIOutput header = (UIOutput) application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        header.setValue(varKey);
        column.getFacets().put("header", header);

        ValueExpression valExpr = expressionFactory.createValueExpression("#{" + var + "." + varKey + "}", String.class);
        UIOutput cell = (UIOutput) application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        cell.setValueExpression("value", valExpr);


        column.setStyleClass(varKey);
        column.getChildren().add(cell);
        component.getChildren().add(column);

        component.getAttributes().remove("columnOrder");
    }
    super.encodeEnd(context, component);
}
```

and am calling it so

```
<my:dataTable var="item" value="#{myBean.collection}" columnOrder="field" />
```

The header gets set correctly, but the cell outputs literally *#{item.field}* rather than evaluating the expression.

The setStyleClass on the column component fails to have the desired effect as well.

I'm guessing that I have got hold of the wrong end of the stick and am going the wrong way about this.

NB. in this reduced example, I'm assuming that columnOrder is a single string and the header simply uses the key value, rather than a list of keys which look up in a bundle.

Comment: I am not 100% on this, but I think the EL value expressions get evaluated to actual values after the INVOKE_APPLICATION phase of the lifecycle and before the `encodeEnd`.  Is there anyway that you can set the ValueExpression before this?

Comment: Aha... I thought that might be the case, but I was a bit scared off by the DataTable code. However, the relevant method, getColumns, turned out to be pretty straightforward and my code worked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@maple_shaft hit the nail on the head.

By moving the code to the class overriding DataTable rather than DataTableRenderer, it all works. Well, that is, after I added in ElContext too.

Updated code is as follows:

```
@Override
public List<Column> getColumns() {
    if (columns == null) {
        columns = new ArrayList<Column>();

        for (UIComponent child : this.getChildren()) {
            if (child.isRendered() && child instanceof Column) {
                columns.add((Column) child);
            }
        }

        Object columnOrder = this.getAttributes().get("columnOrder");
        if (columnOrder != null) {

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            Application application = context.getApplication();
            ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
            ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

            Column column = new Column();

            Object var = this.getAttributes().get("var");
            String varKey = columnOrder.toString();

            HtmlOutputText header = new HtmlOutputText();
            header.setValue(varKey);
            column.getFacets().put("header", header);

            ValueExpression valExpr = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + var + "." + varKey + "}", String.class);

            HtmlOutputText cell = new HtmlOutputText();
            cell.setValueExpression("value", valExpr);
            column.getChildren().add(cell);

            column.setStyleClass(var + "-" + varKey);
            columns.add(column);

            this.getAttributes().remove("columnOrder");
        }
    }

    return columns;
}
```

Comment: I suspected this was the case but didn't want to provide an answer and possibly discourage others to pass up on your question.  Thanks for posting back and answering your own question, you would be surprised how many people can't be bothered with common courtesy.

Comment: İf you override getColumns, other datatable functionality will break. Just a heads up.

Comment: In which case, how am I supposed to extend the functionality?  Or am I not - just copy and paste the entirety of Column.java? (By the way, hello Mr OptimusPrimeFaces ;)

So far I've tested all the PrimeFaces examples and not had any problems. On the other hand, attempting to auto-inject sorting of the the columns does break - but I thought I could live with that and leave it for another time...